# Generic printer driver - Android

Tags: android, printing, driver, wireless

I am trying to send some files (pdf files) to a network printer using an Android program I am developing but the printer is printing random characters instead of the actual document. Using a different app I was able to print to the same printer using what the app called a "*generic printer drive*. I could not find any *generic printer drivers* for android, so I was wondering if this is just an alias or if there exist generic drviers I can install on Android to use wireless printers.

The code I am using to send the file to the printer is:

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
try {
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(IP, Port (9100)), 5000);
    BufferedOutputStream bos;

    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File (fileName));

    int c;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    while ((c = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        bos.write(bytes, 0, c);
    }

    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
    socket.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android has its own [printing framework](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html) which is available from Android 4.4 (API level 19) on wards.

However , if you would instead like to send a file directly to the printer, the file would need to be converted to an emulation which the printer understands like

```
PCL6, BR-Script 3, IBM Pro-Printer XL, Epson FX-850
```

The emulation your printer supports would be available in your printer documentation.

Your *Generic printer drive app* works by converting the PDF to an image and then translates this image into an emulation your printer supports and sends it as bytes to the printer.

Comment: Thanks for the information. However, how can some apps (like PrinterShare) have a "default printer" driver that work on almost any printer?

Comment: Have a look at [Shared printer plugin - CUPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.cups.android) on the playstore and its source at [github](https://github.com/pelya/android-print-plugin-cups). It gives a nice example of how this is done on Android using cups and ghostscript for a variety of printers.

Comment: Thank you @agomes. I believe this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Android has "print drivers", but only through its own [printing framework](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html), not for the sort of direct printer communication that you are performing.